# keep the same factorizing between two data

Tags: python, pandas

We have two data sets with one varialbe col1. 
some levels are missing in the second data. For example let

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["A","A","B","C","D","E"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["A","B","D","E"]})
```

When we factorize df1

```
df1["f_col1"]= pd.factorize(df1.col1)[0]
df1
```

we got

```
    col1    f_col1
0   A   0
1   A   0
2   B   1
3   C   2
4   D   3
5   E   4
```

But when we do it for df2

```
df2["f_col1"]= pd.factorize(df2.col1)[0]
df2
```

we got

```
    col1    f_col1
0   A   0
1   B   1
2   D   2
3   E   3
```

this is not what I want. I want to keep the same factorizing between data, i.e. in df2 we should have something like

```
    col1    f_col1
0   A   0
1   B   1
2   D   3
3   E   4
```

Thanks.

PS: The two data sets not always available in the same time, so I cannot concat them. The values should be stored form df1 and used in df2 when it is available.

Answer (score 3):

You could concatenate the two DataFrames, then apply `pd.factorize` once to the entire column:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["A","B","C","D","E"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["A","B","D","E"]})

df = pd.concat({'df1':df1, 'df2':df2})
df['f_col1'], uniques = pd.factorize(df['col1'])
print(df)
```

yields

```
      col1  f_col1
df1 0    A       0
    1    B       1
    2    C       2
    3    D       3
    4    E       4
df2 0    A       0
    1    B       1
    2    D       3
    3    E       4
```

---

To extract `df1` and `df2` from `df` you could use `df.loc`:

```
In [116]: df.loc['df1']
Out[116]: 
  col1  f_col1
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    C       2
3    D       3
4    E       4

In [117]: df.loc['df2']
Out[117]: 
  col1  f_col1
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    D       3
3    E       4
```

(But note that since performance of vectorized operations improve if you can apply them once to large DataFrames instead of multiple times to smaller DataFrames, you might be better off keeping `df` and ditching `df1` and `df2`...)

---

Alternatively, if you must generate `df1['f_col1']` first, and then compute
`df2['f_col1']` later, you could use `merge` to join `df1` and `df2` on `col1`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["A","B","C","D","E"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["A","B","D","E"]})

df1['f_col1'], uniques = pd.factorize(df1['col1'])
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left')
print(df2)
```

yields

```
  col1  f_col1
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    D       3
3    E       4
```

Comment: Thanks. 
The two data sets not always available in the same time, so I cannot concat them. The values should be stored form df1 and used in df2 when it is available.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution which allows computation of `df2['f_col1']` *after* `df1['f_col1']`.

Answer (score 1):

You could reuse `f_col1` column of `df1` and `map` values of `df2.col1` by setting index on `df.col1`

```
In [265]: df2.col1.map(df1.set_index('col1').f_col1)
Out[265]:
0    0
1    1
2    3
3    4
```

Details

```
In [266]: df2['f_col1'] = df2.col1.map(df1.set_index('col1').f_col1)

In [267]: df2
Out[267]:
  col1  f_col1
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    D       3
3    E       4
```

Incase, `df1` has multiple records, drop the records using `drop_duplicates`

```
In [290]: df1
Out[290]:
  col1  f_col1
0    A       0
1    A       0
2    B       1
3    C       2
4    D       3
5    E       4

In [291]: df2.col1.map(df1.drop_duplicates().set_index('col1').f_col1)
Out[291]:
0    0
1    1
2    3
3    4
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution, but I got errors since the data have duplicated values. 

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Use `drop_duplicates` to remove duplicates in `df1`, check the updated section.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get unique values across both sets of data.  Then create a series or a dictionary.  This is your factorization that can be used across both data sets.  Use `map` to get the output you are looking for.

```
u = np.unique(np.append(df1.col1.values, df2.col1.values))
f = pd.Series(range(len(u)), u)  # this is factorization
```

---

Assign with `map`

```
df1['f_col1'] = df1.col1.map(f)
df2['f_col1'] = df2.col1.map(f)
```

---

```
print(df1)

  col1  f_col1
0    A       0
1    A       0
2    B       1
3    C       2
4    D       3
5    E       4
```

---

```
print(df2)

  col1  f_col1
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    D       3
3    E       4
```